# System.Data.DataRowView exception when inserting row into SQL Server

Tags: .net

Im getting an error No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type every time i click my button.. here's my code..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim insertCommand = <xml>
    INSERT INTO returns(
        Department, 
        Purpose, 
        Item_details, 
        Requested_by, 
        Approved_by, 
        ReturnDate
    ) 
    SELECT
        Department, 
        Purpose, 
        Items_Details, 
        Requested_by, 
        Approved_by, 
        Date 
    FROM borrow 
    WHERE ID = @BorrowID;
</xml>

    Dim param = cmd.CreateParameter()
    param.ParameterName = "@BorrowID"
    param.Value = ListBox1.SelectedValue


    cmd.CommandText = insertCommand.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch SqlExceptionErr As Exception
        MsgBox(SqlExceptionErr.ToString)


    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: -1 The title of your question is not informative. Suggest changing it to something like "System.Data.DataRowView exception when inserting row into SQL Server".

Comment: Have you check the value of ListBox1.SelectedValue? I assume the borrow.ID column is an Integer. Is ListBox1.SelectedValue an integer?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying^^ and sorry the late reply just came home from school.. done i already changed it.. Yes my Borrow.ID column is an integer. i didn't add my ID column in returns and borrow tables because they are both auto increment.. I think i should changed this part WHERE ID = @BorrowID to WHERE Date = @ModifiedDate so that when i transfer the selected rows, the date column in returns table will be updated.. What do you mean ListBox1.SelectedValue an integer?.. you mean the Display Member?.. My Listbox1.SelectedValue is bound to Borrow table and has a display member of Department.

Comment: You should bind Borrow.Id to ListBox.ValueMember then you can use ListBox.SelectedValue. You should a unique identifier to copy the borrow into returns. I doubt your date column is unique.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot it's working now.. now my next problem is after i move my selected row to returns table and i want to add another data again i get this message "The variable name '@BorrowID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure" .. what might be wrong?..

Comment: Oh never mind i already fixed it.. hehe.. i declare both of this code in my form_load so it will be only declared once form is loaded.. Dim param = cmd.CreateParameter()
    param.ParameterName = "@BorrowID"
now the next thing im going to do is update the date of the returns table^^.. tnx for helping me.. i really appreciate it.. more to power to you.. can you give me a good way on how can i update my date in returns table?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrow.Id needs to be bound to your ListBox.ValueMember.

Comment: Hi tnx for helping me.. really appreciate.. i've completed my project.. i'll be doing another project so if i have any problem hope you can help me.. cha...